# Recoding variables in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe that has 6 variables and one of them looks like this:

```
a_title

2 LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]
3 LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),1m,opal,ohne,2 Stucke]
```

As you can see the title is long and confusing. The important data from this long string are just "Typ-3" and "1m or 2m".

My goal would be to recode this long string into something like this -> "Typ-3 2m"

I have tried to solve it by myself and I usually hit the wall. I managed to write this but it is not ok:

```
data$a_title[data$a_title=="Typ-1" | ",1m,"] <- "Typ-1 1m"
```

Comment: Are the strings always structured similarly?

Comment: I'd recommand regex with gsub

Comment: Strings are always structured similarly... it is a dataframe I have pulled from the ebay API.

Comment: Is there something not working/incorrect in my answer? I noticed you accepted and then unaccepted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It solved my problem for the data in the two strings I have provided.. unfortunately not all the data is coded that way. I have solved it like this:                                           data_alu[grep("Typ-1|Typ1|Typ 1", data_alu$a_naziv), "tip"] <- "Typ-1"
data_alu[grep("Typ-2|Typ2|Typ 2", data_alu$a_naziv), "tip"] <- "Typ-2"
data_alu[grep("Typ-3|Typ3|Typ 3", data_alu$a_naziv), "tip"] <- "Typ-3"
data_alu[grep("Typ-4|Typ4|Typ 4", data_alu$a_naziv), "tip"] <- "Typ-4"
data_alu[grep("Typ-5|Typ5|Typ 5", data_alu$a_naziv), "tip"] <- "Typ-5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of people here more skilled at regex than me, but this seems to work on the strings you supplied. It uses two capture groups, in combination with some identifying features around the second group (the comma).

```
dat$typ <- gsub(".+(Typ-[0-9]+).+),([0-9]+m),.+","\\1 \\2",dat$a_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `recode` command from the `car` package. Here is an example. First I generate a vector with the categories you mentioned:

```
x <- c(rep("LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]",3),
 rep("LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),1m,opal,ohne,2 Stucke]",2))
```

This vector looks as follows:

```
> x
[1] "LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]"
[2] "LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]"
[3] "LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]"
[4] "LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),1m,opal,ohne,2 Stucke]"    
[5] "LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),1m,opal,ohne,2 Stucke]"
```

Now I can recode this vector (make sure all the `'`and `"` are in the right place):

```
library(car)
y <- recode(x, "'LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),2m,opal,2 Stucke,4 Stucke]'='Typ1';
 'LED Aluprofil 1m 2m fur LED Streifen Abdeckung ALU[Typ-3 (16121),1m,opal,ohne,2 Stucke]'='Typ2'")
```

Check if it worked:

```
> y
[1] "Typ1" "Typ1" "Typ1" "Typ2" "Typ2"
```

Or transform to a factor:

```
> as.factor(y)
[1] Typ1 Typ1 Typ1 Typ2 Typ2
Levels: Typ1 Typ2
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only two unique strings we're dealing with here, looks like some kind of inventory.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work

```
matches = sapply(c("Typ-\\d", "\\dm"), function(x) regmatches(a, regexpr(x, a)))
paste(matches, collapse=" ")
```

although I find Heroka's answer most elegant so far ;)